# Join sys.types to sys.parameters

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to list columns in a user defined table.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    sys.types t
WHERE
    t.is_user_defined = 1 AND t.is_table_type = 1
```

How do I join sys.types to sys.parameters so I can get the information I need?

Here is how I would define the user defined table:

```
CREATE TYPE MyTable AS TABLE (
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
  , Name NVARCHAR
)
```

My desired output would be

```
TableType | Parameter | ParameterID
-----------------------------------
MyTable   | Id        | 0
MyTable   | Name      | 1
```

Comment: What does your table scheme look like?

Comment: Edit for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
    SELECT
      t.name,
      c.name,
      c.column_id
    FROM sys.table_Types t
    JOIN sys.columns c ON t.type_table_object_id = c.object_id
    WHERE
      t.is_user_defined = 1 AND t.is_table_type = 1
```